# "No such file or directory" "org-publish"

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I am following tutorial on https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html.
I move point to the end of this line and press C-x C-e to load org-publish:

```
(require 'org-publish)
```

It worked yesterday.  Now it gets this backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "org-publish")
  require(org-publish)
  eval((require 'org-publish) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  #f(compiled-function (eval-last-sexp-arg-internal) "Evaluate sexp before point; print value in the echo area.\nInteractively, with a non `-' prefix argument, print output into\ncurrent buffer.\n\nNormally, this function truncates long output according to the\nvalue of the variables `eval-expression-print-length' and\n`eval-expression-print-level'.  With a prefix argument of zero,\nhowever, there is no such truncation.  Such a prefix argument\nalso causes integers to be printed in several additional formats\n(octal, hexadecimal, and character when the prefix argument is\n-1 or the integer is `eval-expression-print-maximum-character' or\nless).\n\nIf `eval-expression-debug-on-error' is non-nil, which is the default,\nthis command arranges for all errors to enter the debugger." (interactive "P") #<bytecode 0x1f84db>)(nil)
  #f(compiled-function (&rest _it) #<bytecode 0x25ee78d>)()
  eval-sexp-fu-flash-doit-simple(#f(compiled-function (&rest _it) #<bytecode 0x25ee78d>) #f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x21bb4b1>) #f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x21ba8b1>))
  eval-sexp-fu-flash-doit(#f(compiled-function (&rest _it) #<bytecode 0x25ee78d>) #f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x21bb4b1>) #f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x21ba8b1>))
  esf-flash-doit(#f(compiled-function (&rest _it) #<bytecode 0x25ee78d>) #f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x21bb4b1>) #f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x21ba8b1>) #f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x21ba0b1>))
  ad-Advice-eval-last-sexp(#f(compiled-function (eval-last-sexp-arg-internal) "Evaluate sexp before point; print value in the echo area.\nInteractively, with a non `-' prefix argument, print output into\ncurrent buffer.\n\nNormally, this function truncates long output according to the\nvalue of the variables `eval-expression-print-length' and\n`eval-expression-print-level'.  With a prefix argument of zero,\nhowever, there is no such truncation.  Such a prefix argument\nalso causes integers to be printed in several additional formats\n(octal, hexadecimal, and character when the prefix argument is\n-1 or the integer is `eval-expression-print-maximum-character' or\nless).\n\nIf `eval-expression-debug-on-error' is non-nil, which is the default,\nthis command arranges for all errors to enter the debugger." (interactive "P") #<bytecode 0x1f84db>) nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-eval-last-sexp #f(compiled-function (eval-last-sexp-arg-internal) "Evaluate sexp before point; print value in the echo area.\nInteractively, with a non `-' prefix argument, print output into\ncurrent buffer.\n\nNormally, this function truncates long output according to the\nvalue of the variables `eval-expression-print-length' and\n`eval-expression-print-level'.  With a prefix argument of zero,\nhowever, there is no such truncation.  Such a prefix argument\nalso causes integers to be printed in several additional formats\n(octal, hexadecimal, and character when the prefix argument is\n-1 or the integer is `eval-expression-print-maximum-character' or\nless).\n\nIf `eval-expression-debug-on-error' is non-nil, which is the default,\nthis command arranges for all errors to enter the debugger." (interactive "P") #<bytecode 0x1f84db>) nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

How to troubleshoot?
I don't understand the error message and I don't know Lisp.

UPDATE 1:

org-publish is not listed in list-packages.

UPDATE 2:

The tutorial uses two different "require".

```
(require 'ox-publish)
(require 'org-publish)
```

Comment: See if you can use org-export-dispatch instead? You can use htmlize and ox-twbs packages for nice html exports.

Comment: Sounds like `org-publish` is not in your `load-path`.

Comment: @A_P I am using org-publish to keep the *.html files separated from our *.org files.

Comment: @Drew You were right, org-publish was not in load-path.
So I added it, now load-path value is ("~/.emacs.d/org-publish/" ...
But it still gets the same error and backtrace.

Comment: If `~/.emacs.d/org-publish/` is the correct location of `org-publish.el` then your setup is strange. How did you install `org-mode`?

Comment: The official master has `ox-publish.el` [in its `lisp` directory](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp) but no `org-publish.el`. Try to replace `(require 'org-publish)` with `(require 'ox-publish)`.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to says `(require ox-publish)` just as @Tobias has suggested.

Comment: @Tobias, I installed org-mode by uncommenting "org" in .spacemacs dotspacemacs-configuration-layers.

Comment: @NickD, I just noticed that the tutorial uses two different "require":
(require 'ox-publish) and (require 'org-publish).
Hence the confusion.  I guess they should both say, "(require 'ox-publish)"?

Comment: It looks like `org-publish.el` has been renamed to `ox-publish.el`. One finds `org-publish.el` in `org` of some years ago. But, I didn't find the commit that renamed it to `ox-publish.el`.

Comment: Yes, I see the different `require`s: they should both require `ox-publish`. Can you send a bug report to the org-mode ML? @Tobias: it was done gradually: first `org-e-publish.el` was introduced as an experimental version with the new export engine (commit b5082974c83a3a4838db86025edce857b11e5847), then the new export framework was made the default with new names `ox-*` (commit 8dd2bfc2915b969271160eb5d76dcc581b4121b8), then the old framework was moved into contrib (commit 03a9191dd3be397715c8f919ae656d1c8221f8fb).

Comment: You do not need to call `(require 'ox-publish)`. `org-publish-project` is auto-loaded. Did you configure `org-publish-project-alist` correctly? Maybe you need to set the parameters `:base-directory` and `:org-publishing-function` correctly.

Comment: @Tobias, my org-publish-project-alist configuration looks correct to me, I posted it in the main question, UPDATE 3.

Comment: Did you check your *Messages* buffer? It should contain some information about the publishing process and maybe some errors as well. FWIW, I copied the definition of `org-publish-project-alist` above, modified the paths for my setup, added a simple org file to the specified `base-directory` and did `M-x org-publish RET org RET` with no errors. Moreover, there was a corresponding html file in the publishing directory afterwards.

Comment: I ran through the org-publish process again, this time with the *Messages* buffer open.  To my surprise, the html files published.  Maybe last time I forgot to C-x C-e.

Comment: @NickD, I want to change the tutorial from (require 'org-publish) to (require 'ox-publish).
So I send a bug report to the org-mode ML?
What is "ML"?

Comment: Sorry, I should not have been lazy: ML = Mailing list. See [here](https://orgmode.org/community.html) for details.

Comment: @NickD, Thanks.  I sent the (require 'ox-publish) correction to the ML.

Comment: I saw it - thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90990/discussion-between-nickd-and-wolfv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(require 'org-publish)` should be `(require 'ox-publish)`.

Here is the directory structure:

```
[~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html]
$ tree
.
├── org
│   ├── css
│   ├── f1.org
│   ├── f2.org
│   └── index.org
├── org-publish-project-alist.el
├── public_html
│   ├── f1.html
│   └── index.html
└── publish_html_notes.org
```

Here is the file containing my org-publish-project-alist configuration:
~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/org-publish-project-alist.el

```
(require 'ox-publish)    ;C-x C-e to load org-publish
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
("org-source"            ;org-source files to be transformed into html files
 :base-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/org/"
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :headline-levels 4
 :auto-preamble f
 )

("org-static"
 :base-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/org/"
 :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
 :publishing-directory "~/Documents/developer/editors/emacs/publish_html/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
 )

("org" :components ("org-source" "org-static"))
      ))                 ;C-x C-e and repeat after every change to org-publish-project-alist.el
```

Then performed the next steps in the tutorial:

```
Move to the end of the first line and press C-x C-e to load org-publish. Now go to the end of the last line and press C-x C-e again. 
...

To publish your Org-mode files just type M-x org-publish-project RET org RET
```